# Kivy Anchor and gridlayout centering

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am using anchor layout to hold widgets, my widget is a gridlayout, the issue is, I want a compact login display UI, however, I am getting 3 contorls near, and logout button at end, all are not together (should not have much spacing) and should be centered in Anchor Layout.

I am getting it as which is not looking good:
[image]

Codes are as follows:

**main**.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from formcontrol import FormControl

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title="sample App"
        self.formcontrol = FormControl()
        return self.formcontrol

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

FormControl.py:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from login.logincodes import LoginControl
from login.logincodes import AfterLogin

class FormControl(AnchorLayout):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        super(FormControl,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        c= LoginControl()
        c.setparent(self)
        self.add_widget(c)

    def changewidget(self,to):
        if to == 'AfterLogin':
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.add_widget(AfterLogin())
```

logincodes.py:

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class LoginControl(GridLayout):
    _parentwidget=None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginControl,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.userid.text='Welcome'

    def setparent(self,parent):
        self._parentwidget=parent

    def changewidget(self,to):
        self._parentwidget.changewidget(to)

    def login_pressed(self,button):
        print(button.text)
        print(self.userid.text)
        print(self.userpw.text)
        self.changewidget('AfterLogin')

    def close_pressed(self,button):
        print(button.text)
        exit()


class AfterLogin(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(AfterLogin,self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

my.ky file:

```
<LoginControl>:
    rows: 3
    cols: 1

    userid: userid
    userpw: userpw

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '32dp'
        Label:
            text: 'User ID'

        TextInput:
            id: userid
            text: 'some password'

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '32dp'
        Label:
            text: 'Password'

        TextInput:
            id: userpw
            password: True
            text: 'some password'

    Button:
        text: 'Login'
        on_press: root.login_pressed(self)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '32dp'

    Button:
        text: 'Close'
        on_press: root.close_pressed(self)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '32dp'



<AfterLogin>:
    rows: 1
    Label:
        text: 'Logged In'
```

Please make me learn where I went wrong in configuring the UI and I dont want to use a float layout which is like using points to place widgets. I am new to both Python and Kivy.  Your support and advices are valuable to me to improve,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `GridLayout` you specify `rows` = 3 and `cols` = 1, which means the layout has space for 3 children. When it gets to laying out the Close button, all the rows and cols have been used up so the Close button goes to the default position `(0, 0)`. I would just specify `cols` and leave `rows` out - it will use as many rows as necessary to lay out the children.

Second, this isn't a problem, but there's a quicker way to set all of the children's height to 32dp. Rather than specifying `size_hint` and `height` on all of the children, you can instead set `row_default_height` and `row_force_default` on the `GridLayout`.

Finally, your `GridLayout` is still taking up all the space, which is why it's not centering in the `AnchorLayout`. This is easily solved with a `GridLayout` due to the `minimum_height` property - set `height` to `minimum_height` and `size_hint_y` to `None`, and it will center.

Putting it all together:

```
<LoginControl>:
    cols: 1
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: '32dp'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
```

[image: centered GridLayout example]

Comment: Yup, that worked, however, how can I center the buttons, they are taking the entire width, I tried it as 'size_int_x: None' and 'width: '50dp' but still is taking entire width. Only for one control without forcing at grid level.

Comment: `GridLayout` ignores its children's `size_hint_x` and `width` when `cols` is set. Setting `size_hint_x` and `width` will work, just wrap each button you want to center in another `AnchorLayout`.

Comment: Thank you.  That helps me understanding kivy layout in more detail. Kivy must become more like WPF, it is very good for UI. Thank you.