# How to center a button in MDBoxLayout

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i just started study Kivy and have a question how to centrize a button in mdboxlayout, after read and tried many examples i didn't found a way to do that.
main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, SwapTransition

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition=SwapTransition())
        screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='screen_one'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name='screen_two'))
        return screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<screenone>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        rows: 2
        size: root.width, root.height
        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size: (self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2)
            md_bg_color: 0, 1, 1, .5
            Button:
                text: 'button'
                size_hint: (None, None)
                size: (self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2)
                pos: (self.parent.width / 4, self.parent.height / 4)
#                position: {"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5}
```

i'm really sorry if i missed any already created same task and thanks all who will response

my scope is to create four buttons, each in his area and centralized on the center X and Y. in the screen u can see where is the button and where i expect to be
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dxNs.png)

Comment: Please explain what you have tried to solve the problem so we don't repeat that. Does this help?https://stackoverflow.com/q/35572211/12846804

Comment: @OCa Thanks so much! this really helped me, but is really so hard to center horizontally and vertical a button in a cell of gridlayout ? may be there is a simpler way without creating so much classes ?

Comment: glad to hear that helped; now personnally I have no knowledge of this. You need to describe what you have tried, in the body of the question, in order to get the upvotes for a question well asked, then your post's visibility improves and hopefully attracts more volunteers.

Comment: Also "centrize" does not exist as a word, to my knowledge, so you probably should not let that in your title.

Answer (score 1):

Find a shorter way. Will place result here, may be it will helps someone too.
As inspiration i used answers from questions:

1. [link to question provided by @Oca user:12846804](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572211)
2. [another question about centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649750)

main.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, SwapTransition
from kivymd.app import MDApp



class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition=SwapTransition())
        screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='screen_one'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name='screen_two'))
        return screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv
canvas sections can be deleted, i used them just for see the are of each anchorlayout

```
<screenone>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        rows: 2
        size: root.width, root.height
        AnchorLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1  # red
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size: (self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2)
            Button:
                text: 'button'
                size_hint: (None, None)
                size: (self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2)
                pos: (self.parent.width / 4, self.parent.height / 4)
        AnchorLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 132, 0, 1 # green
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size: (self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2)
            Button:
                text: 'button'
                size_hint: (None, None)
                size: (self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2)
                pos: (self.parent.width / 4, self.parent.height / 4)
        AnchorLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 150, 150, 150, 1 # white
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size: (self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2)
            Button:
                text: 'button'
                size_hint: (None, None)
                size: (self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2)
                pos: (self.parent.width / 4, self.parent.height / 4)
        AnchorLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 55, 55, 0, 1  # yellow
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size: (self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2)
            Button:
                text: 'button'
                size_hint: (None, None)
                size: (self.parent.width / 2, self.parent.height / 2)
                pos: (self.parent.width / 4, self.parent.height / 4)
```

i suppose there is a shorter way without repeating the code for each AnchorLayout and Button but currently this is a working solution.
Thanks all and have a good day and code :)